# How to find the frequency of a value, in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary, frequency

Say we have the following array of dictionaries:

```
var dictionary_demo = [
                         [
                            {country: "georgia", value: sunny},
                            {country: "france", value: rainy}
                         ],
                         [
                            {country: "georgia", value: sunny},
                            {country: "france", value: gloomy}
                         ],
                         [
                            {country: "georgia", value: rainy},
                            {country: "france", value: dry}
                         ]
                      ]
```

How would I get the output that tells me:

in georgia: sunny occurs 2 times, and rainy occurs 1 time.

In france: rainy occurs 1 time, gloomy occurs 1 time, and dry occurs 1 time

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

With an array of arrays (proper terminology for a dictionary in JS is array), it would be easy to use the `flatMap` to get extract all values from the inner arrays into the outer array.  From there you can iterate over the flattened array and collect the values you want.

For this example, I might use the `array.reduce` method to transform the resulting flat array into an object with a key for each country, and the value being another object with keys for each weather type, and value of the frequency of occurrence.

```js
var dictionary_demo = [
                         [
                            {country: "georgia", value: "sunny"},
                            {country: "france", value: "rainy"}
                         ],
                         [
                            {country: "georgia", value: "sunny"},
                            {country: "france", value: "gloomy"}
                         ],
                         [
                            {country: "georgia", value: "rainy"},
                            {country: "france", value: "dry"}
                         ]
                      ]

function weatherFrequency(arr) {
  // flatten the array
  const flatArr = arr.flatMap(a => a)

  // use flattened array to transform the values into frequencies
  const sortedArr = flatArr.reduce((accum, { country, value }) => {

    // check if key exists, if not, add it
    if (!accum[country]) accum[country] = {}

    // check if weather type exists, if so add 1, if not, assign 1
    accum[country][value] ? accum[country][value] += 1 : accum[country][value] = 1

    // return the accumulator for the next iteraction of `reduce`
    return accum
  }, {})
  return sortedArr
}

// check resulting object from the `reduce` function
console.log(weatherFrequency(dictionary_demo))

// produce a string with the values you want
const countryWeather = weatherFrequency(dictionary_demo)

// use string interpolation to extract values you need
console.log(`in georgia: sunny occurs ${countryWeather.georgia.sunny} times, and rainy occurs ${countryWeather.georgia.rainy} time`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dictionary_demo = [
   [
      {country: "georgia", value: "sunny"},
      {country: "france", value: "rainy"}
   ],
   [
      {country: "georgia", value: "sunny"},
      {country: "france", value: "gloomy"}
   ],
   [
      {country: "georgia", value: "rainy"},
      {country: "france", value: "dry"}
   ]
]

var res = dictionary_demo.reduce(function(acc,e){
    
    return acc.concat(e);

},[]).reduce(function(acc, e){

    if(!acc[e.country])
        acc[e.country] = {[e.value]: 1};
    else
        acc[e.country][e.value] = (acc[e.country][e.value] ||  0) + 1;

    return acc;
    
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an array of array, you can flat that arrays with `depth = 2`, and then you can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to build the desired output.

```js
const arr = [   [      {country: "georgia", value: "sunny"},      {country: "france", value: "rainy"}   ],   [      {country: "georgia", value: "sunny"},      {country: "france", value: "gloomy"}   ],   [      {country: "georgia", value: "rainy"},      {country: "france", value: "dry"}   ]];
const result = arr.flat(2).reduce((a, {country, value}) => {
  const current = (a[country] ?? (a[country] = {[value]: 0}));
  a[country][value] = (a[country][value] ?? 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```